# How to change value under memory address in C inline assembly (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

In one of the exercises in my assembler course we have to create a program that will change all uppercase letters in char* to lowercase.

```
 char *a = "AAA BB CCC";
 char *b;
 asm(
 ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
   "xor ecx, ecx;"
   "xor eax, eax;"
   "lea eax, [%[a]];"  // getting address of the first char into eax
  "loop:"
   "inc ecx;" // loop variable
   "cmp ecx, 10;" // 10 cycles for very character in *a
   "jne lowercase;"
   "jmp end;"
 "lowercase:"
   "mov bl, [eax];" // copy value stored under eax address to bl
   "add bl, 32;" // make it lowercase in ASCII
   "mov [eax], bl;" // copy it back to address stored in eax
   "inc eax;" // move pointer to the next char
   "jmp loop;"
 "end:"
   "lea %[b], [eax];" 
 ".att_syntax prefix;"
   : [b] "=r" (b)
   : [a] "r" (a)
  : "eax", "ebx", "ecx"
 );
```

My idea was to get address of the first char, increase it by 32 (making it lowercase in ASCII), save it on the same address, than move pointer to the next char and so on. Getting first char and adding 32 to it works fine, its this line that throws "Segmentation fault":

```
"mov [eax], bl;"
```

From what I understand it should change value under address held in eax to value of bl. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm pretty new to this and everything I found so far on the net leads me to believe that this is how I should do it.

Comment: While there are a number of things wrong with this code, the one you are asking about is probably due to the fact that constant strings (like "AAA BB CCC") are typically allocated in read-only pages.  Trying to write to a read-only page gives an AV.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd
Thanks for the answer. I will try to find another way save lowercase characters then. Could you elaborate on what else is wrong?

Comment: Switching to intel using the `.intel_syntax` directive is also wrong. If you want intel, just compile using `-masm=intel`. Otherwise the compiler will expand your constraints wrong.

Comment: @Jester That part is not mine. We have to put code in between ".intel_syntax" and ".att_syntax;", can't change anything outside of that :/

Comment: I tried to think of a polite way to list things, but comments have size limits. So: You zero eax right before assigning a different value to it. You have jne+jmp when only 1 jump is needed. Your assignment to %[b] comes after you have modified the value of eax.  Using b is redundant, since you are modifying a in place (ie a and b will always point to the same thing). You are hard-coding the length (instead of looking for the trailing 0). You assume all characters will be UC instead of allowing for LC or non-alphabet. NB Writing output to a correctly-sized output buffer allows more flexibility.

Comment: To have that string writeable define `a` as char array, not pointer: `char a[] = "AAA BB CCC";` If you can't change code outside of intel/att directives, you are out of luck, as you have no writeable memory buffer available to write the result into.